# Docker: ENTRYPOINT can't execute command because it doesn't find the file

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a container from `node js` image and I have configured my `Dockerfile` as shown:

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

VOLUME ./:/usr/src/app
ENTRYPOINT [ "npm run watch" ]
```

In the `package.json` I have a script called `watch` than runs the gulp task named `watch-less`.

If I run `npm run watch` in my local environment the command works but when I try running the container it doesn't and shows the next error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"npm run watch\": executable file not found in $PATH".

Comment: try # VOLUME ./:/usr/src/app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "npm run watch" ]
```

This is an incorrect json syntax, it's looking for the executable `npm run watch`, not the executable `npm` with parameters `run` and `watch`:

With the json syntax you need to separate each argument. You can use the shell syntax:

```
ENTRYPOINT npm run watch
```

Or you can update the json syntax like (assuming `npm` is installed in `/usr/bin`):

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/npm", "run", "watch" ]
```

You also have an incorrect volume definition:

```
VOLUME ./:/usr/src/app
```

Dockerfiles cannot specify the how the volume is mounted to the host, only that an anonymous volume is defined at a specific directory location. With a syntax like:

```
VOLUME /usr/src/app
```

I've got strong opinions against using a volume definition inside of the Dockerfile described in [this blog post](https://boxboat.com/2017/01/23/volumes-and-dockerfiles-dont-mix/). In short, you can define the volume better in a docker-compose.yml, all you can do with a Dockerfile is create anonymous volumes that you'd need to still redefine elsewhere if you want to be able to easily reuse them later.

Comment: It works! Thanks for helping and your explanation :)

Answer (score 5):

If you use the list notation for `ENTRYPOINT`, that is, with the `[`brackets`]`, you must separate the arguments properly.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "watch"]
```

Right now it is trying to find a file literally named "`npm run watch`" and that does not exist.